# Angular 4 - Children route makes entire outlet blank

Tags: html, angular

Whenever i click on this link, it result a blank outlet.

> This worked properly **Before** I add `'contact_content':['contact']}` to the link.

**menubar.component.html** (*KaltimMenubarComponent*)

```
<ul>
  <a routerLink="/kaltim" routerLinkActive="active">
    <li>
      <img src="assets/news.svg" alt="news"><span>B e r i t a</span>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/kaltim', { outlets: {'kaltim_content':['about']} }]" routerLinkActive="active">
    <li>
      <img src="assets/about us.svg" alt="about us"><span>T e n t a n g<br>K a m i</span>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/kaltim', { outlets: {'kaltim_content':['contact'], 'contact_content':['contact']} }]" routerLinkActive="active">
    <li>
      <img src="assets/contact.svg" alt="contact"><span>K o n t a k</span>
    </li>
  </a>
  </ul>
  <a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" class="start_page">
    <img src="assets/start.svg" alt="start">H A L A M A N<br>U T A M A
  </a>
```

**contact.component.html** (*KaltimContactComponent*)

```
<router-outlet name="contact_content"></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StartComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'kalteng', component: KaltengComponent, children: [
    { path: 'contact', component: KaltengContactComponent, outlet: 'kalteng_content' },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactFormComponent, outlet: 'contact_content' },
    { path: 'about', component: KaltengAboutComponent, outlet: 'kalteng_content', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '', component: KaltengMenubarComponent, outlet: 'kalteng_menubar'},
    { path: '', component: KaltengHomeComponent, outlet: 'kalteng_content', pathMatch: 'full'},
  ] },
  { path: 'kaltim', component: KaltimComponent, children: [
    { path: 'contact', component: KaltimContactComponent, outlet: 'kaltim_content' },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactFormComponent, outlet: 'contact_content' },
    { path: 'about', component: KaltimAboutComponent, outlet: 'kaltim_content' },
    { path: '', component: KaltimMenubarComponent, outlet: 'kaltim_menubar'},
    { path: '', component: KaltimHomeComponent, outlet: 'kaltim_content', pathMatch: 'full'},
  ] },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'start', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

**start.component.html** (*StartComponent*)

```
<a routerLink="/kaltim" routerLinkActive="active" class="main"></a>
<a routerLink="/kalteng" routerLinkActive="active" class="main"></a>
```

**kaltim.component.html** (*KaltimComponent*)

```
<main>
  <router-outlet name="kaltim_menubar"></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="kaltim_content"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

**contact-form.component.html** (*ContactFormComponent*)

```
<!-- Usual Forms -->
<label>...</label>
<input>...</input>
```

Comment: Add `pathMatch: 'full'` to all routes with `path: ''` which have no child routes and are not redirect routes. You also have 2 routes with `path: ''` at the top level.

Comment: added `pathMatch: 'full'` to my `KaltimMenubarComponent` and `KaltimHomeComponent`, and now it brokes the menubar, the menubar should shown on every pages (permanent/fixed entity). I also moved the `path: ''` to the bottom/lowest.

Comment: I missed that you used `outlet` on many routes. I never saw a working example where `outlet` is used in route configuration. I don't think using routes to add static parts is a good approach anyway.

Comment: btw, I just need to remove `pathMatch: 'full'` from the MenubarComponent (menubar works).

Comment: But the child routes still don't work?

Comment: Yes, one more thing you should know that `KaltimMenubarComponent` outlet is located in `KaltimComponent` which its outlet is located in `Root`. And `ContactFormComponent` outlet is located in `KaltimMenubarComponent`.

Comment: I don't think I can help you here.

Comment: Please, I'll edit the Topic more detailed so that you can understand me well.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've edited the topic, hope you understand it better.

Comment: As I said, I haven't seen a working example with `outlet` in routes configuration. I'm not able to help you here. Perhaps someone else.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Problem solved. LOL. I could have just put the selector of `ContactFormComponent` which is `<app-contact-form>` into the `contact.component.html`. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Should've put `<app-contact-form>` (`ContactFormComponent`'s selector) inside `contact.component.html` rather than uses the routing for that.